# If-Else in View?

Tags: c#, sql

I have this code in my C# application:

```
EmployeeFirstName = gc.Key.CommissionType.GetValueOrDefault() == CommissionTypeTypes.Personal ? gc.Select(ec => ec.EmployeeFirstName).FirstOrDefault() : string.Empty, //c.EmployeeFirstName,
```

and I want to have it in SQL

That means if my column "CommissionType" is the char 'P', take the value from EmployeeFirstName (and connect it), if not, make it null.

Columns are: EmployeeFirstName, CommissionType.

Comment: Look up CASE statements in SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have IF-ELSE in a view. It is a single select statement. But you could use a case expression for this.

```
case when CommisionType = 'P' then EmployeeFirstName end
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Wouldn't matter under most collations but certainly better to be precise. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try a `case` statement:

```
case
when CommissionType = 'P'
then EmployeeFirstName
else null -- you can leave this one out but put it there for clarity
end
EmployeeFirstName
```

Comment: Seems we both answered with the same thing at the same time. :)

Comment: @ReneK: need more help?